# Linqpad not resetting static variables between runs unless the code changes

Tags: linqpad

Let's say I write this little linqpad snippet and run it, I get what I expect

[image]

But when I hit F5 again, the list will have two items in it:

[image]

I was not expecting it to do this and can't figure how why it would.

The list will be growing everytime I run it unless I do something to the code, even add a comment. Then it will reset to one entry.

Is this by design? If so why?
I'm on 5.08.01

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is by design.  It does not reset the Application Domain unless you do one of the following:

1) Use Ctrl+Shift+F5 to reset it on demand

or

2) Go into Edit/Preferences/Advanced and set "Always use Fresh Process per execution" to True.  This will reset every time you run a script

or

3) Put the following code into your query (this tells LINQPad to use a fresh domain next time you run):

```
Util.NewProcess = true;
```

As for why, there are probably multiple benefits but I'd say performance is the main one. You could put the results of an expensive query in a static variable and only run it the first time.

Comment: after 4 yrs, #2 becomes "Always use Fresh Process per execution". thought everyone ought to know.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @AceMark, I updated the answer to reflect the new verbage.